# Does db.session.commit() terminate a SQLAlchemy session?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does `db.session.commit()` terminate a SQLAlchemy session?

I suspect the answer is no, and that I have to additionally call `db.session.close()`, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It commits the current transaction. You can still issue additional queries after you commit. A transaction will be started automatically if you do. The relevant documentation is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#closing).